# How to select and modify all caption fields at once in a Word document?

Tags: ms-word, field

I have been trying to change the numbering style of my figure and table captions. All of my headings are in Roman numerical. However, I want Arabic numerical in my caption numbering. Could anyone tell me an easy way to do it at once? Below is an example:

Heading title: "Chapter V". My captions appear as "Figure V-2". However, I want them to appear as "Figure 5-2"

Also, is there any way I can select all figure caption fields at once and edit their field code?

Answer (score 2):

To change in one caption: Press Alt-F9 and remove \* ARABIC .
Ctrl+A, F9 to update fields.

Now to change in all captions: try with a search and replace (Ctrl+H) to replace `SEQ Figure \* Arabic \s 1` with `SEQ Figure \s 1`

To modify all field codes, you could use search & replace or you can modify field codes in VBA this way:

```
Sub ChangeAllFields()
'does not process headers/footers
    Dim oFld As Field
    For Each oFld In ActiveDocument.Fields
        fld.Code = Replace(fld.Code, "SEQ Figure \* ARABIC \s 1", "SEQ Figure \s 1")
    Next oFld
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

When you insert captions from now on, change the numbering in the dialog box that pops up.  I think you'll have to change it every time, because Word (correctly) defaults to matching the Roman numerals in your chapter headings to Roman numerals in your captions.  If you want to be abnormal, you'll have to change from the default every time you insert a caption, or change them all using one of the methods from Toon Flores.

p.s.  I said "abnormal" because every style manual I've ever seen would frown on what you are doing.